# In a Join, How to Ensure Each Group In Table B Joins to Every Row in Table A

Tags: mysql, sql, view

My SQL dialect is MySQL. I am creating a view on two tables.

I have TableA which looks like this:

```
| date | value |
|------|-------|
| 1    | 100   |
| 2    | 150   |
```

I have TableB which looks like this:

```
| date | group | name  |
|------|-------|-------|
| 1    | d     | alice |
| 1    | e     | bob   |
| 2    | d     | clark |
| 2    | e     | mick  |
```

I want to do a join and combine them on the `date` column, in such a way the each group in B gets a join on A. To be more clear, here's what the output data should look like:

```
| date | group | value | name  |
|------|-------|-------|-------|
| 1    | d     | 100   | alice |
| 1    | e     | 100   | bob   |
| 2    | d     | 150   | clark |
| 2    | e     | 150   | mick  |
```

So this is a pretty contrived example, just to make it easy to read in markdown. But some details about my actual problem:

1. I have a large of number of groups, so many nested derived tables is not feasible, and would slow the view query time too much.
2. I need to generate columns that are some function of both tables (e.g. some output like `value + name`, which is obviously nonsensical with this example's types)

I have tried using:

```
SELECT value, name, group
FROM TableA
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.date = TableB.date
```

The output in this case just takes one of the groups, and ditches the rest.

What is the syntax for this?

Comment: Based on the sample data, an `INNER JOIN` will be sufficient. Also your query looks fine to me, what do you mean by ditches the rest? Can you show the output you get?

Comment: @sagi, `INNER JOIN` did the trick. Thanks! Make an answer and I'll give you the green tick of destiny. I can't believe I didn't try that. I am so used to Pandas where their syntax for this operation is `outer`, so I presumed that it would have to be an outer join, and wondered why SQL was giving me trouble.

Comment: No problem man, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data sample you've shared, it looks like you're looking for an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `RIGHT JOIN`.

```
SELECT value, name, group
FROM TableA
JOIN TableB
 ON TableA.date = TableB.date
```